# checking the existence of a string in another string using recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I wanna write a program that checks the existence of a string in another string using recursive function (not allowed to use any method such as in , find etc.

I've written that like this :

```
def intersection(str1, str2):
        if str2 in str1:
            print('yes')
        else:
            print('no')

        intersection(str1, str2)

intersection('abcd abs', 'abs')
```

this code runs too much how can i fix this problem .

by the way, i have to write it recursively and not allowed to use any set method or string method that checks the input strings automatically.

Comment: Your recursive function does not have a base case; it will always call itself with the same arguments, over and over. What you got here is an infinite loop.

Comment: @Robby the Belgian how to write the base?

Comment: You'll need to think about how you want to solve your problem. Sketch out on paper how you would go about this. Then, convert it to a recursive solution. Then work out what your base case is and how your recursive call should work.
But first think, before you write code.

Comment: You say *"not allowed to use any method such as in"* but then your code begins with `if str2 in str1:`

Comment: How did you decide to name your function `intersection`? This word has a very precise meaning and that meaning s not "is the second string inside the first string?"

Answer (score 0):

For recursion, you need a base case and recursion part (which usually involves reducing the problem).

```py
def is_substring(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) < len(str2):
        return False
    return str1[:len(str2)] == str2 or is_substring(str1[1:], str2)

print(is_substring('abcd abs', 'abs')) # True
```

Here, recursion stops as `False` when `str1` shorter than `str2` (i.e., base case). Otherwise, the function compares the beginning of `str1` to `str2`. If they are not the same, then because of `or`, the function calls itself with smaller part of `str1`.